# Node.js Sequelize ORM model issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize the Node.js ORM for my web application. Facing the following issue when i start my Node server.

Following are the further details

**Error**:

project_directory_path\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:322

**model.init(attributes, options);**

**TypeError: model.init is not a function**
    at Sequelize.define (project_directory_path\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:322:11)
    at module.exports (project_directory_path\models\sequelize\app_config_setting.js:2:41)
    at Sequelize.import (project_directory_path\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:379:32)
    at project_directory_path\models\index.js:34:48
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object. (project_directory_path\models\index.js:31:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object. (project_directory_path\server.js:12:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:972:3

**Version**:

node version v5.0.0,
sequelize version: "^4.4.2",
dialect: "mysql"

**index.js** file (to load all the models)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelizeConnection = 
require('../configs/dbConnection.js').exposeSequelizeConnectionObj();
var sequelizeModelDir = path.join(__dirname, 'sequelize');
var dbModels = {};

fs.readdirSync(sequelizeModelDir)

//avoiding the index.js and all other files
//expect the model files
.filter(function (file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
})

//iterating on each models and importing it
//in sequelize connection object
.forEach(function (file) {
    var dir = 'sequelize/';
    var models = sequelizeConnection.import(path.join(sequelizeModelDir, file));
    dbModels[models.name] = models;
});

//exposing all the models
module.exports = dbModels;
dbModels.sequelize = sequelizeConnection;
```

**One of my model** (just to get the idea)

```
module.exports = function (sequelize,DataTypes) {
var roles = sequelize.define(
    'roles',
    {
        id: {autoIncrement: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11), allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
        role_name: {type: DataTypes.ENUM('super_admin'), allowNull: false},
        code_name: {type: DataTypes.ENUM('super_admin'), allowNull: false},
        row_status: {type: DataTypes.ENUM('active','inactive'), allowNull: true}
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
        paranoid: true,
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'roles'
    }
);
return roles; };
```

**Database Connection file:**

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelizeConnectionObj = new sequelize(process.env.DB_DATABASE_NAME, 
process.env.DB_USERNAME, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
host: process.env.DB_HOSTNAME,
dialect: 'mysql',
define: {
    timestamps: false
},
dialectOptions: {
    multipleStatements: true
},
logging: false,
pool: {
    max: 15,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
   }
 });

   exports.exposeSequelizeConnectionObj = function connectSequelize() {
   return sequelizeConnectionObj;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved by updating the node module

i-e npm update

just update your node modules.

Comment: Glad you manage to solve your issue. Your code seems like to have been generated by sequelize-cli, I'm I right ? I think there's issue with the last version of Sequelize which is not supported yet (I think). I have create a small repository with the same code as you, but I think it's simpler > https://github.com/sapher/sequelize-boilerplate